# Make chatGpt 4097 token limit for forex data

Tags: python, openai-api

I have forex data in CVS and I am trying to feed it into ChatGPT and ask questions based on this data. Right now what I am doing is because my dataset is big like more than 4000 tokens and I am using contextual memory technique to make chunks. So it is working okay but I want to make it more accurate. Can u guys give me any idea how can I solve this issue using this kind of data?

Tried contextual memory and langchain.  I want to have more accurate responses on the whole dataset.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: On one hand, I'd suggest taking a look at the strategies that LlamaIndex exposes via its "response synthesizer" modules. On the other hand, I'm not sure that what you're doing is a good use case for ChatGPT at all; it's trained to reason about text, not numerical data, and in general it makes more sense to use a model designed-to-purpose.

Comment: yes, u are right about ChatGPT, just getting insights and summary from the data. like if u give some code and tell the ChatGPT to explain it. this is what i am doing so what i want now is to make chatGpt understand whole data and answer me on this. without making chunks